# IEnumerator IEnumerable vb to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

Hello everyone i'm new to c# language i was use vb.net,
in below what is the error with this code and why, thank you

```
vb.net code
Class SplitString
Implements IEnumerable
Implements IEnumerator

Private currentPosition As Integer = 0
Private m_Sentence As String
Property Sentence() As String
    Get
        Return m_Sentence
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        m_Sentence = Value
        Me.Reset()
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Current As Object Implements IEnumerator.Current
    Get
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim tmpLength As Integer = 0
        For counter = Me.currentPosition To Me.Sentence.Length - 1
            If Me.Sentence.Chars(counter) = " "c Then
                Exit For
            Else
                tmpLength += 1
            End If
        Next
        Current = Me.Sentence.Substring(Me.currentPosition, tmpLength) ' ok 
        Me.currentPosition += tmpLength + 1
    End Get
End Property

Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean Implements IEnumerator.MoveNext
    If Me.currentPosition > Me.Sentence.Length - 1 Then
        Me.Reset()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function

Public Sub Reset() Implements IEnumerator.Reset
    Me.currentPosition = 0
End Sub

Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return Me
End Function
End Class
```

but when i try this code to c# i get Error

```
c# code
class SplitString:IEnumerable,IEnumerator
{
    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private string m_Sentence;
    public string Sentence
    {
        get { return m_Sentence; }
        set
        {
            m_Sentence = value;
            this.Reset();
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }


    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int tmpLength = 0;
            for (counter = this.currentPosition; counter <= this.Sentence.Length - 1; counter++)
            {
                if (this.Sentence[counter] == ' ')
                {
                    break; 
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpLength += 1;
                }
            }
            Current = this.Sentence.Substring(this.currentPosition, tmpLength); // Error
            this.currentPosition += tmpLength + 1;
            return functionReturnValue;
        }
    }
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
       if (this.currentPosition > this.Sentence.Length-1)
       {
           this.Reset();
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           return true;
       }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        this.currentPosition=0;
    }
}
```

error: Property or indexer ‘Example.splitstring.current’ cannot ve assigned to – it is read only

Comment: Try to replace `Current = this.Sentence.Substring...` with `var functionReturnValue = this.Sentence.Substring...`

Comment: @YacoubMassad thank mr yacoub but  Why am I forced to write "function Return Value" I want to understand exactly why this error occurred

Comment: Interesting. I guess it has to do with VB6 backwards compatibility. There you can assign a value to the method-name instead of returning it. So this works only in the readonly-property-getter, nowhere else.

Comment: To set the return-value in a function, you must use `return someValue;` (which also ends the function), you cannot assign the value to the function (old-style VB idiom)

Comment: @HansKesting: Actually you _can_ do that. It compiles and works. But of course only in the getter of the property and not from outside and you should use `Return ...` instead.

Comment: Although the property is read-only in Visual Basic .NET, but did not show any error in vb.net .... Why

Comment: @NourAhmed - see the answers why this does not show as an error

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Assigning to the function name works in C#??

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: no, of course not. Because this is a getter, in VB.NET it's a different(old) syntax to return a value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
Current = Me.Sentence.Substring(Me.currentPosition, tmpLength) ' ok
```

is the "old" VB way of setting a return value in a method without using the `Return` keyword. In general, the following VB code

```
    myMethodName = ...
    ...some other code...
End Function
```

can be rewritten as

```
    Dim someTempVariable = ...
    ...some other code...
    Return someTempVariable
End Function
```

(as long as `some other code` does not exit the method).

The same is true for properties. Thus, we first rewrite your *old* VB code to *new* VB code:

```
        ...
    Next
    Dim returnValue = Me.Sentence.Substring(Me.currentPosition, tmpLength) 
    Me.currentPosition += tmpLength + 1
    Return returnValue
End Get
```

and now the translation to C# should be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

(For VB6 backwards compatibility/Legacy reasons) VB.NET Allows you to return values from a `Property` or `Function` by setting the `Function`/`Property` name to a value.

From the Docs: [Function Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6xxtk8kx.aspx)

> "... The procedure returns this value in one of two ways:..."
>
> - "...It assigns a value to its own function name in one or more
>     statements of the procedure. Control does not return to the calling
>     program until an Exit Function or End Function statement is
>     executed..."

e.g.

```
Public Function TestFunc() As String
    TestFunc = "bar"
    'some code
End Function
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
Public Function TestFunc() As String
    Dim temp = "bar"
    'some code
    Return temp
End Function
```

So in your VB code, it is setting the Property Name in order to return a value:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Test As String
    Get
        Test = "foo"
    End Get
End Property
```

or in your case:

```
Current = Me.Sentence.Substring(Me.currentPosition, tmpLength)
```

There is no *direct* equivalent to this in C# as `return` would return immediately. The best So the equivalent C# would be to set a temporary variable and return that:

```
var temp= this.Sentence.Substring(this.currentPosition, tmpLength);
//some more code
return temp;
```

Whenever I access a Property from within the class in VB, I always prefix my properties with `Me.` which avoids this nasty behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Your Current and functionReturnValue variable is not define in you code plese define in function.

```
   Current = this.Sentence.Substring(this.currentPosition, tmpLength); // Error
   return functionReturnValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared a `set` block for `Current` property, so it is read-only. You need to implement it, something like:

```
public object Current
{
    get
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int tmpLength = 0;
        for (counter = this.currentPosition; counter <= this.Sentence.Length - 1; counter++)
        {
            if (this.Sentence[counter] == ' ')
            {
                break; 
            }
            else
            {
                tmpLength += 1;
            }
        }
        Current = this.Sentence.Substring(this.currentPosition, tmpLength); // Error
        this.currentPosition += tmpLength + 1;
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Current = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i don't not declared a set block for Current because when you implement interface IEnumerator the visual studio will generete current property without a set block


public object Current
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }